# Basic sass, how to Inherit property in nested class

Tags: css, sass

I am rewriting a project from CSS to SCSS, and I have a problem refactoring.

My code converted is:

```
.flex {
  display: flex !important;

  &-down {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  &-center {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &-center-left {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &-evenly {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-evenly !important;
  }
  &-around {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-around !important;
  }
  &-between {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-between !important;
  }
  &-column {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: flex-start !important;
    align-content: center !important;
    flex-direction: column !important;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am repeating all the time the property `display: flex !important;`
Since I declare it the very first instruction of the container class .flex, there is any way the nested classes can get that property in a less verbose way, more elegant? because I don't see the point to repeat  `display: flex !important;` or  `display: inherit !important;` constantly, and I don't do it, the result classes in CSS won't have that property.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will your elements have the `.flex` class as well as a `.flex-<one of the options>`? If so, you could just remove it from everywhere except the first `.flex`

Comment: do you assign these classes in your html as `class="flex flex-between"`?

Comment: I use it in the HTML like `class="flex-center-left"`, changing to  `class="flex flex-between"` will make me go through all the HTML code...

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to add anything in the other you can still make it like :

```
.flex {
  display: flex !important;

  &-down, &-center, &-center-left, &-evenly, &-around, &-between, &-column{
    display: flex !important;
  }
  &-down {
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
  &-center {
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center;

       &-left {
          align-items: center;
       }
  }

  &-evenly {
    justify-content: space-evenly !important;
  }
  &-around {
    justify-content: space-around !important;
  }
  &-between {
    justify-content: space-between !important;
  }
  &-column {
    align-items: flex-start !important;
    align-content: center !important;
    flex-direction: column !important;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 - @mixin and @include**

Mixins allow you to define styles that can be re-used throughout your stylesheet.

Example :-

```
  @mixin flexbox
 {
 display:-webkit-box; // old
 display:-moz-box; // old
 display:-ms-flexbox; // ie
 display:-webkit-flex; // new
 display:flex; // new
 }

div {
 @include flexbox();
 }
```

**Method 2 :-**
You can have multiple CSS declarations for the same properties by separating them with commas:

```
.flex {
  display: flex !important;

  &-down, &-center, &-center-left, &-evenly, &-around, &-between, &-column{
    display: flex !important;
  }
```